# C# TCP Server/Client Object Transmission/Serialization/De-Serialization Increasingly Using Memory Help Required

Tags: sockets, object, serialization, tcp, deserialization

**First and Foremost,**

### Thanks in advance to all who may provide help, criticism, advice.

**Language:** C#

---

**Objective:** TCP Server/Client For Image And Object Transmission.

---

**Server Scenario:** 
Server will listen for client connection.

Upon client connection server will receive byte[] data from socket

Server will convert byte[] it into (Type) object.

Server will then use this (Type)Object to update WPF Image Control

---

**Client Scenario:**

Client will create object ready for transmission.

Client will converting object to stored byte[].

Client will connect to server and send object via a socket

---

**Issue:**

I am unsure why this process is increasing 60-100MB of memory used per second.

I would like to know if Byte[] Chunking would be a worth while solution *(if so could you please direct me to a resource or provide a solution)*

It feels like it is not cleaning up after itself properly or re-using variables.

---

**Notes:**

The Bitmap Capture and Convert to Byte[] is working great AFAIK this isn't the issue, but I can post code if problem is not in the code below or if others would benefit.

The ObjecttoByte[] and ByteArrayToObject code works and is slightly modified from other stack overflow posts, like wise I can post it if the problem is not in the code below or if others would benefit.

---

**Server Listener Code:**

```
public void StartServer()
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Initialize Variables For Server
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        int recv;
        byte[] data;

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Configure Server Listener
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Bind Socket To IPEndpoint And Listen
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        newsock.Bind(ipep);
        newsock.Listen(10);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Accept New Connection
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");
        Socket client = newsock.Accept();

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Verify Client Endpoint Connection
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", clientep.Address, clientep.Port);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Start Reading From Socket While Client Connected
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            data = new byte[500000]; // Create Buffer For Object

            recv = client.Receive(data); // Ensure Client Has Sent Data
            if (recv == 0)
                break;

            //-------------------------------------------------------
            // Create Test Object And De-Serialize 
            //-------------------------------------------------------   
            TestObject to = new TestObject(); //Object For Storage
            Console.WriteLine("Server Object Size: " + data.Length); // Check Length For Interest

            var dataToObject = ByteArrayToObject(data); // Convert Object Byte[] to Object
            to = (TestObject)dataToObject; // Store Converted Byte[] Object into Typed Object

            Console.WriteLine("Server De-Serialized Object from Client."); // Provide Information
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Server TestObject: " + to.testString); // Extract And Notify Object String Data

            //-------------------------------------------------------
            // Update Main GUI Image (WPF)
            //-------------------------------------------------------   
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap)); // Create Type Converter
                Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(to.testBmp); // Cast into Bitmap from Byte[] 
                imgRemoteDisplay.Source = ByteMonImaging.GetBitmapSource(bitmap1); // Display Bitmap  
                bitmap1 = null;
                tc = null;
            }));

            //-------------------------------------------------------
            // Clean Up
            //-------------------------------------------------------   
            dataToObject = null;
            data = null;
            to = null;
            GC.Collect();
            //-------------------------------------------------------
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", clientep.Address);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Close Listener
        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        client.Close();
        newsock.Close();
    }
```

---

**Client Connection Code:**

```
public void ConnectClient()
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Configure Server Connection
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Establish Connection To Server
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        try
        {
            server.Connect(ipep);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return;
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Start Sending Object To Server While Connected
        //-------------------------------------------------------            
        while(server.Connected)
        {
            TestObject to = new TestObject(); // Create blank object store

            to.testString = "TestObject String Here"; // Set Blank Object Test String
            var bmpToSend = ByteMonImaging.CaptureBitmap(); // Set Blank Object Test  Bitmap
            to.testBmp = ByteMonImaging.ImageToByte(bmpToSend); // Convert Bitmap to Byte[]    

            var byteArray = ObjectToByteArray(to); // Pack Object into Byte[]
            Console.WriteLine("Client Object Size: " + byteArray.Length); // Curious Byte[] Size
            server.Send(byteArray); // Send Byte[] Object Via TCP
            Console.WriteLine("Client Sent Serialized Object to Server."); // Notify Where We Are At

            bmpToSend = null; // Clean Up
            to = null; // Clean Up
            byteArray = null; // Clean Up
            GC.Collect(); // Clean Up (Added for Checks)
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        // Close Connection to Socket And Server
        //-------------------------------------------------------      
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting from server...");
        server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        server.Close();
    }
```

---

**Cause of Memory Consumption Located**

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
            // Update Main GUI Image (WPF)
            //-------------------------------------------------------   
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap)); // Create Type Converter
                Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(to.testBmp); // Cast into Bitmap from Byte[] 
                imgRemoteDisplay.Source = ByteMonImaging.GetBitmapSource(bitmap1); // Display Bitmap  
                bitmap1 = null;
                tc = null;
            }));
```

---

**Solution:** The problem was the hBitmap was causing memory leak when invoking. Using the finally clause I was able to use externdll to delete the object.

```
 [DllImport("gdi32")]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr ipObj);
 public static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource b;
        try
        {                                
             b = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using. It looks like Java, right?

Comment: Updated C# ; Sorry for not providing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** The problem was the hBitmap was causing memory leak when invoking. Using the finally clause I was able to use externdll to delete the object.

```
 [DllImport("gdi32")]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr ipObj);

 public static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource b;
        try
        {                                
             b = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        }
        return b;
    }
```